# Array of strings and other parameters in POST request using Moyo Alamofire

Tags: swift, rest

In my application, We have to send array of strings as one parameter and some other single string as other parameters and also need to send image data to server using REST API. For image data we are planning to convert into base64encoding string from 5Mb size images and add as one parameter in the same request. Could anyone help me with best approach in Moya/Alamofire?

Comment: `multiform/form-data` might be better than base64 encoding, as it's usually used for "large" data (like images, files, etc.)

Comment: Yes, totally we are going to upload 5 images at the max and size will be 5MB

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can use multipartFormData for uploading image with parameter here we use "AlamofireObjectMapper" :---

```
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper

    
func postWithImage(server_url : String, _ end_point: EndPoint, param: [String: Any], image: UIImage?, withName: String?, completion: @escaping (DataResponse<Response>) -> Swift.Void) {
        
            
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
                
                for (key, value) in param {
                    print(key)
                    print(value)
                    MultipartFormData.append(("\(value)" as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
                
                if let img = image {
                    MultipartFormData.append(img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!, withName: withName!, fileName: "test.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
                
            }, to: server_url+end_point.rawValue, method: .post, headers: nil) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Response>) in
                        completion(response)
                    }
                    break
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    showToast(message: error.localizedDescription)
                    break;
                }
       } 
      
 }



enum EndPoint: String {
    case signup = "/signup"
}



class Response: Mappable {
    
    public var code: Int?
    public var message: String?
    public var status : String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
        code <- map["code"]
        message <- map["message"]
        status <- map["status"]
   }
}
```